# Mac admin user want to share Virtual Machines with VirtualBox

Tags: mac, virtualbox

The admin user of a Mac has VirtualBox installed with 3 VM: Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 8. I want to share this configuration for all other users. How can I do that? When other users open their VirtualBox, there aren't VMs loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain the VMs (.vid) files in a shared folder. Moreover, you need to create in VirtualBox and reference the virtual machines in each account of your OS.